# How to figure where is q0.solution() or q0.hint() ? | Kaggle

Tags: python, kaggle

I am taking this course in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/codeapplied/exercise-syntax-variables-and-numbers) and lesson one; I ran this command.

```
from learntools.core import binder; binder.bind(globals())
from learntools.python.ex1 import *
print("Setup complete! You're ready to start question 0.")
```

then they asked me to run

```
q0.hint()
# q0.solution()
```

I am not sure what is `learntools.core` , not sure `learntools.python`

But with the basic knowledge I got, I know we are trying to import the class in which `q0.solution` exist.

If I want to know or explore the whole class

```
from learntools.core import binder; binder.bind(globals())
from learntools.python.ex1 import *
```

How is it possible and what command do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Both are modules...

```
from learntools.python.ex1 import *
```

This line imports all variables, classes, and functions defined in that module. That's probably where `q0` is defined.

You can see all variables of the current scope by printing both `locals()` and `globals()`

Or look at the source code
https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools/blob/master/learntools/python/ex1.py

Comment: Sorry! yeah they are called modules, not classes. And I know that we are trying to import the modules. But how did you find the GitHub repos for Kaggle? If its some other project or website, can we find the GitHub repos of theirs too if they exist.

Comment: That link there is for the Kaggle github org. I don't know what you're looking for. The solutions probably aren't public

Comment: I dont mean solutions. I am asking how did you figure out the Kaggle's gitHub.

Comment: I simply searched "learntools Python"